# processingからPythonにソケット通信

Tags: python, python3, processing

processingからPythonに文字列のみのソケット通信の仕方を探しています。

[PythonからProcessingへソケット通信でデータを送る | Qiita](https://qiita.com/FukuoAkiyama/items/7c7f88c8c7d6363ca581)

上記のサイトの逆をしたいです。
調べてみたのですが、自力では見つかりませんでした。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

質問にあるサイトのコードと同じく、同一のマシン内で`Processing`から`Python`へ一方的にテキストメッセージを送るだけのコードのサンプルです。

Processing側（詳しくは http://www2.kobe-u.ac.jp/~tnishida/course/2012/programming/ServerClient.pdf ）
サーバー側を先に起動し、ポート番号はサーバに合わせます。

```
import processing.net.*; 
Client client;

void setup() { 
  client = new Client(this, "127.0.0.1", 50007); 
} 

void draw() { 
  client.write("hello");  
}
```

Python側（[Python ドキュメント](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/socket.html#example)）

```
# Echo server program
import socket

HOST = ''                 # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 50007              # Arbitrary non-privileged port
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen(1)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print('Connected by', addr)
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if not data: break
            print(data)
```

Comment: 教えていただいてありがとうございます。無事に通信することができました。リアルタイムでずっと表示されるため変更があったときのみ表示に変えようとPython側のprint部分をwhile文に挟んでみたのですが、転送内容ではなくポート番号と思われるものが表示されてしまいました。何か対策方法を教えていただけないでしょうか？

Comment: 追記ですみません。processing側から1回の送信でもと思っています。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 上記解決しました。通信方法を教えていただきありがとうございました。

Comment: 無事できてよかったです。通信のプログラムを書くのは結構難しいです。複雑なことをさせようと思ったらPythonのFlaskかBottleでサーバーを立てて、HTTP Requests for Processing を使ってアクセスしたほうが楽な場合もあると思います。

Comment: いただいたものを使って自分の作りたいものを作っているのですが、通信はすごく難しいですね…   現状pythonを起動した後にprocessingを起動させていますが、逆は複雑な内容になるのでしょうか？どちらも動かしつつpython の動作中にprocessingから来たデータを使いたいため、いただいたものをdefに入れた場合どうしようもなく、困っています。

Comment: 回答のリンク先をみると返送の機能が追加できます。それで、processing側でポーリングをすればpythonからprocessingにデータを送ることは可能です。通信の場合はメッセージのやり取りをどうするか（プロトコル）をはっきり決めないといけないです。

Comment: 送受信ができるのですね。システムを考えた結果参考サイトと同じようにProsessingをサーバーにしようと奮闘しているのですが、回答で教えていただいたサイトの8ページを見ながらPython側の受信の部分を書こうとしているのですが、標記の仕方はどのようにしたらいいのでしょうか。質問ばかりですみません。

Comment: 何度もすみません。.recvでできました。逐次おしえてくださり本当にありがとうございました。